# git gc fatal error bad object refs/remotes/origin/deleted/deleted.002

Tags: git

When I run git gc, I get this error

> fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/deleted/deleted.002
>
> fatal:failed to run repack

Everything else is fine, only git gc gives the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this I went and deleted the reference by deleting the file 
`.git/refs/remotes/origin/deleted/deleted.002`

`deleted` is a system directory and won't be visible directly. so just open the file using the path or use command prompt to delete the file.

You can save a copy also if you want restore the file later